# Recycler View item deleted even if its first checked and then Unchecked

Tags: android

Multiple items in my recycler view can be checked and deleted by adding them to a integer array list for position and string array list for phone number. They are added when the isChecked() property of the checkbox is true.

```
    holder.delCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            objCheck.setSelected(isChecked);
            holder.delCheckbox.setChecked(objCheck.getSelected());
            if (holder.delCheckbox.isChecked()) {

                arrPos.add(holder.getAdapterPosition());

                arrNo.add(arrSuitcaseContacts.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).number);
            }
```

But if I uncheck an item, the item will remain added in the arraylist and will be deleted by the click of the button.

I just want to delete only those items which are checked finally. How do I do that?

For example in the image Sam will also be deleted along with the Geeta because I checked Sam and unchecked it afterwords.

[image]

**ContactsDeleteAdapter.java**

```
public class ContactsDeleteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsDeleteAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<SuitcaseContacts> arrSuitcaseContacts;
    ArrayList<String> arrNo = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> arrPos = new ArrayList<>();
    DBHelper dbHelper;


    public ContactsDeleteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SuitcaseContacts> arrSuitcaseContacts) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrSuitcaseContacts = arrSuitcaseContacts;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContactsDeleteAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.delete_contact_list, parent, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ContactsDeleteAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final SuitcaseContacts objCheck = arrSuitcaseContacts.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

        holder.image.setImageResource(arrSuitcaseContacts.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).image);
        holder.name.setText(arrSuitcaseContacts.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).name);
        holder.number.setText(arrSuitcaseContacts.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).number);


        holder.delCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                objCheck.setSelected(isChecked);
                holder.delCheckbox.setChecked(objCheck.getSelected());
                if (holder.delCheckbox.isChecked()) {

                    arrPos.add(holder.getAdapterPosition());

                    arrNo.add(arrSuitcaseContacts.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).number);
                }

                /*if (!holder.delCheckbox.isChecked()){

                    arrPos.remove(position);
                    arrNo.remove(position);
                }*/

                Log.d("CHKS", String.valueOf(holder.delCheckbox.isChecked()));
                Log.d("Selected no", arrNo.toString());
            }
        });


    }

    public void DeleteContacts(ArrayList<String> phone, ArrayList<Integer> arrPos) {
        Collections.sort(arrPos, Collections.reverseOrder());

        for (int i = 0; i < arrPos.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("arrPos", arrPos.get(i).toString());

            arrSuitcaseContacts.remove(arrPos.get(i));
        }

        dbHelper = DBHelper.getDB(context);

        if (!dbHelper.checkDB()) {
            dbHelper.createDB(context);
        }

        dbHelper.openDB();

        String[] phoneArr = phone.toArray(new String[phone.size()]);

        dbHelper.deleteMulContacts(phoneArr);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Contacts Deleted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrSuitcaseContacts.size();
    }

    void delClickActivator() {
        DeleteContacts(arrNo, arrPos);

    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView name, number;
        CheckBox delCheckbox;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgContact);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
            delCheckbox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delCheckbox);


        }
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p94dH.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. The key point was to remove the elements from arrPos and arrNo which were added after selecting a checkbox item BUT they must be removed using an INDEX represented by an int counter which here is addCounter

```
 if (holder.delCheckbox.isChecked()) {

                arrPos.add(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                arrNo.add(arrSuitcaseContacts.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).number);
                addCounter++;
                }
```

What I did was initialized a static addCounter to -1 and whenever a checkbox item is selected, addCounter increments by ++ so for example if a first item is selected using a checkbox the arrPos and arrNo will add items to the 0th and the addCounter will increment by ++ from -1 and will be 0 as well

And whenever the item is unchecked from checbox it will be removed using the index represented by addCounter :

```
if (!holder.delCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                arrPos.remove(addCounter);
                arrNo.remove(addCounter);
                addCounter--;

            }

            if (!holder.delCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                arrPos.remove(addCounter);
                arrNo.remove(addCounter);
                addCounter--;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use commented lines with small changes:

```java
if (holder.delCheckbox.isChecked()) {
  arrPos.add(holder.getAdapterPosition());
  arrNo.add(arrSuitcaseContacts.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).number);
} else {
  arrPos.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
  arrNo.remove(arrSuitcaseContacts.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use your item position , and add it to a list (selectedContactToDelete) whenever checkbox is checked and then remove all the items which their position is among selectedContactToDelete from your arrSuitcaseContacts , and then apply a `NotifyDataSetChanged` on your `adapter`

and reversely , if you uncheck an element remove it from the list (selectedContactToDelete).